# Can we change chart type in amCharts using dropdown?

Tags: angular, charts, amcharts

Let's say I have initially loaded Pie chart and I want user to change it to Line or any other type of chart from a dropdown. How can we achieve it in amCharts? I have seen it in HighCharts but not able to find a solution for amCharts.

Comment: There's no way to change chart type of the chart object. You will need to dispose the old object, and create one anew. That said, you can re-use the same `Root` object.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try something like this

```
document
    .getElementById("chartType")
    .addEventListener("change", function () {
      var selectedChartType = document.getElementById("chartType").value;
      changeChartType(selectedChartType);
    });

  // Function to change chart type
  function changeChartType(selectedType) { // the functions should be under if else statement
      if (selectedType === "pie") { //put the pie chart function here}
      else if (selectedType === "line") {//put the line chart function here}
//your data should be like this
series.data.setAll([
        { category: "Category 1", value: 100 },
        { category: "Category 2", value: 200 },
        { category: "Category 3", value: 300 },
        { category: "Category 4", value: 400 },
        { category: "Category 5", value: 500 }
    ]);
```